How extensively was German communication decrypted during the 1930s & 1940s?
RE: Marxists.org
In letter 288 of this Stalin-Roosevelt correspondence archive Stalin talks about faulty information from George Marshall about the Balaton offensive.  This was long after the German encryption was cracked.  That raised the question for me about how far reaching the interception and decryption was from the UK office that handled the German Enigma encrypted communications.  I wonder how likely the UK and USA forces really had correct information about the Balaton offensive plans or other major operations on the eastern front.

I believe that  you're posing many different questions:

How exetensively was german communication decrypted
--> yes, look for enigma
How much did Americans know of the offensive
--> don't know if an authoritative answer is possible through open source
Did they told the soviet everything they knew
--> likely not (but still, don't know if an authoritative answer is possible), as at the end of the war Russian and Americans were not so much allied anymore...


@DanM: Also important that from about late October 1944 Hitler was convinced that the Allies were reading German codes. Hence the surprise success of Wacht am Rhein (ie Battle of the Bulge), since nothing about it was ever transmitted with Enigma. Likely similar with Balaton.

Seems like there was a question before where one of the answers mentioned that the deciphering of messages after the codebreaking wasn't instant or trivial, and there was a firehose of German coded material, so they had to pick and choose what to decode. Its not like they could just read all German comms in realtime.

Nor were all communications actually intercepted (such as those sent by wire), nor were all  ciphers used by the Germans were regularly attacked (such as the T52 teleprinter machine known as "Sturgeon" to the Allies, used for comms down to division level).

The last few Enigma intercepts were decoded only recently. But I feel the OP is taking a few mental shortcuts here. Even if you had all communication of the enemy, decoded, you still have to get to the right conclusions. Operations like these don't have a full dossier about them transmitted that would tell you everything. You get hints, references, some troop movement orders etc.; it still takes an intelligence agency to sift through the plethora of information and create proper predictions.

Stalin also had some really good sources in Nazi high command, after ignoring them for the beginning of the war, so what he might have been doing was talking up what he was able to know and talking down what the Brits passed on.

@DevSolar Yes, it is almost as if you have to dream up tricks concerning imaginary failed water supplies to really know what is going on.

Neither the US nor the UK were particularly willing to let the USSR in on their code breaking activities; especially since they, both the US and the UK, were also working on cracking Soviet codes.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Huh? Failed water supplies? I have no idea what you are talking about.

@DevSolar Oh, pre-Midway had a partial intercept of IJN commands.  The US knew something was coming to "AF", but there were iirc 3 candidate locations for "AF".   So the US arranged to leak that Midway was running out of water in the clear.  Next thing, the IJN says that "AF" is running out of water.  i.e. AF == Midway.  One question I've been meaning to ask is what the alternates were and what was leaked for them.  https://warontherocks.com/2016/06/the-battle-of-midway-the-complete-intelligence-story/  Std spy stuff:  leak different stories see what gets thru.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Ah, yes. I actually knew the story, I just wasn't thinking "Pacific" in the context of the question. Thanks for the explanation.

For an article that addresses the headline question succinctly, see Deutch (1977). The body of the question goes in a rather different direction then the headline though. There is a huge amount of research published about how decrypted signal intelligence impacted the war, but none of it mentions Balaton / Operation Spring Awakening as far as I can tell.

"This was long after the German encryption was cracked." Nazi Germany used many different types of encryption, not just the famous Engima machine which was for mobile and tactical use. For example, Lorenz. Some were cracked, some weren't, some were cracked and improved and cracked again, some weren't cracked during the war. Some could be decrypted quickly, others would take days or months. The question should be narrowed, perhaps to "How much information about Operation Spring Awakening did the Allies get via cryptography?"
